# nftables chain priority not working

Tags: ubuntu, debian, firewall, redhat, nftables

So I have two input chains, `input` and `dyn` which is dynamically generated.

However the rules of `dyn` just don't work because of `input`. I've tried setting the priority of `input` to `1`, and the `dyn` to `0` even `-200`. Still nothing.

When I flush the `input` rules, then `dyn` works.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
sudo nft list ruleset
table inet filter {
chain input {
    type filter hook input priority filter + 1; policy accept;
    iif "lo" accept
    ct state established,related accept
    tcp dport 299 ip saddr 3x.xx.xx.xx accept
    icmpv6 type { destination-unreachable, packet-too-big, time-exceeded, parameter-problem, echo-request, echo-reply, nd-router-solicit, nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-solicit, nd-neighbor-advert, 148, 149 } accept
    ip6 saddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type { mld-listener-query, mld-listener-report, mld-listener-done, mld2-listener-report, 151, 152, 153 } accept
    counter packets 10 bytes 5255 drop
}

chain dyn {
    type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
    iif "lo" accept
    ct state established,related accept
    ip saddr 2x.xx.xx.xx udp dport 8999 log prefix "dyn" accept
    ip6 saddr xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::9999 udp dport 8999 log prefix "dyn" accept
    ip saddr 2x.xx.xx.xx tcp dport 7999 log prefix "dyn" accept
    ip6 saddr xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::9999 tcp dport 7999 log prefix "dyn" accept
    ip saddr 2x.xx.xx.xx icmp type echo-request log prefix "dyn" accept
    ip6 saddr xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::9999 icmp type echo-request log prefix "dyn"
    ip saddr 2x.xx.xx.xx tcp dport 6999 log prefix "dyn" accept
    ip6 saddr xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::aaaa tcp dport 6999 log prefix "dyn" accept
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each chain hooks into Netfilter: as long as a packet exists, Netfilter will call all chains hooking in the current phase (eg: input).

What this means is that each chain provides a chance to get the packet dropped. Once the packet is dropped, it doesn't exist anymore: remaining chains won't be called for traversal since there's nothing to be used for traversal: the packet already disappeared.

So whatever the priority order of the two chains, when each chain has its own rule to accept or drop a packet, **independently** from the other chain, the final outcome is a logical AND between each outcome, where *drop* means *false* and accept means *true*:

```
drop   AND drop   = drop
drop   AND accept = drop
accept AND drop   = drop
accept AND accept = accept
```

This is reminded in `nft(8)` in the [`VERDICT STATEMENT`](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#VERDICT_STATEMENT) section:

> `accept`
>
> Terminate ruleset evaluation and **accept the packet. The packet can
> still be dropped later by another hook**, for instance accept in the
> forward hook **still allows one to drop the packet later** in the
> postrouting hook, or **another forward base chain that has a higher
> priority number and is evaluated afterwards in the processing
> pipeline**.
>
> `drop`
>
> Terminate ruleset evaluation and drop the packet. **The drop occurs
> instantly, no further chains or hooks are evaluated. It is not
> possible to accept the packet in a later chain again**, as those are not
> evaluated anymore for the packet.

If you want to avoid this, then the evaluation must not be independent. For example you can pass a message between the first chain and the 2nd chain (in order of hook and hook's priority) using a firewall mark to be interpreted as "decision already made, accept this packet". This requires cooperation from both sides, so can't be slapped on an unaware tool (eg: can't add this to a ruleset handled by *firewalld* without modifying *firewalld* to account for this, either as the message creator or as the message consumer.

For your case, you could replace your ruleset with a variation of  this:

```
table inet filter {

chain markandaccept {
    meta mark set 0x900d accept
}

chain input {
    type filter hook input priority filter + 1; policy accept;
    meta mark 0x900d accept
    iif "lo" accept
    ct state established,related accept
    tcp dport 299 ip saddr 3x.xx.xx.xx accept
    icmpv6 type { destination-unreachable, packet-too-big, time-exceeded, parameter-problem, echo-request, echo-reply, nd-router-solicit, nd-router-advert, nd-neighbor-solicit, nd-neighbor-advert, 148, 149 } accept
    ip6 saddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type { mld-listener-query, mld-listener-report, mld-listener-done, mld2-listener-report, 151, 152, 153 } accept
    counter drop
}

chain dyn {
    type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
    iif "lo" goto markandaccept
    ct state established,related goto markandaccept
    ip saddr 2x.xx.xx.xx udp dport 8999 log prefix "dyn" goto markandaccept
    ip6 saddr xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::9999 udp dport 8999 log prefix "dyn" goto markandaccept
    ip saddr 2x.xx.xx.xx tcp dport 7999 log prefix "dyn" goto markandaccept
    ip6 saddr xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::9999 tcp dport 7999 log prefix "dyn" goto markandaccept
    ip saddr 2x.xx.xx.xx icmp type echo-request log prefix "dyn" goto markandaccept
    ip6 saddr xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::9999 icmp type echo-request log prefix "dyn"
    ip saddr 2x.xx.xx.xx tcp dport 6999 log prefix "dyn" goto markandaccept
    ip6 saddr xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::aaaa tcp dport 6999 log prefix "dyn" goto markandaccept
}
}
```

This is an example made without any simplification, I'm sure better can be done.

So whenever the *dyn* chain deems a packet should stay accepted, the packet is tagged (internally, in the current network stack only) with a mark. The first test in the altered *input* chain is to check for this mark: if present, the packet is immediately accepted without further processing: the decision made in the first chain is honored in the 2nd chain.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you.